# how can I empty magento 2 orders, customer and products data reset to 1

Tags: magento2, orders, delete

> how can I empty Magento 2
>
> order
>
> customers
>
> products data to reset 1
>
> how I can do this??

when i run in sql

```
MySQL said: Documentation #1146 - Table 'magento_db.gift_message' doesn't exist
```

but the table is there in the database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Be safe:** make a backup of your SQL first.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**Truncate order tables:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
```

**Truncate Customer tables:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option`;
```

**Truncate Review tables:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `review`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_detail`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_entity_summary`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_store`;
```

**Truncate Product tables:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
```

**Truncate Categories tables:**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;


INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,0,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0); 
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,32,0,2,1),(2,32,1,2,1); 
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,33,0,2,'default-category');
```

and at last, run:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation #1146 - Table 'magento_db.gift_message' doesn't exist

Comment: The default Magento 2.2.x and 2.3.x have **`gift_message`** table. Which version are you using?

Comment: magento 2.2.6 .

Comment: Then the table **gift_message** should be there in the database. hence the query should run.

Comment: i have prefix   mg_table name

Comment: Then you need to add prefix while executing the queries.

Comment: then i have another doubt

Comment: how i can set all ids like product id and customer id s are start from 1

Comment: When the tables will be truncated, it will start new records with 1 automatically.

Comment: so , i no need to alter tabel set  AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Comment: I think NO. It should work without set AUTO_INCREMENT=1; because we are **truncating tables** (not deleting records).

Comment: super..............+1

Comment: i have one doubt .....
how i can delete url related tables....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96643/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-arora-and-prabhakaran7).

Comment: This will work for Magento 2.2.5 or not?

Comment: Delete the old index at store id 1 For elastic search is there any solution for this product not reflecting on frontend

Comment: Yes, This will work for Magento 2.2.5. For elastic search, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Customers and orders table all I need and this works well on version 2.3.5

Answer (score 2):

For cleaning products data :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

for customer data clear :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `login_as_customer_assistance_allowed`;

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

For order related data reset :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

**I hope its work for you.**

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'magento_db.gift_message' doesn't exist

Comment: something wrong in your database, normally when you setup m2 than its created.

Comment: i don't understand ....

Comment: but that table is there in db

Comment: This will work for Magento 2.2.5 or not?

Comment: Delete the old index at store id 1 For elastic search is there any solution for this product not reflecting on frontend