# How I can solve unable to save stock item in magento 2 while saving product

Tags: magento2, product, category, stock

I deleted all the products and categories via

> SQL queries (i used this answer  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283404/73525 )

while saving new product I got the error Unable to save Stock Item

Exception.log

```
[2019-07-27 07:09:08] main.CRITICAL: Unable to save Stock Item {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): Unable to save Stock Item at /home/goodma20/project1.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:183, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`goodma20_test25072019`.`mg_cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `MG_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `mg_cataloginventory_stock` (`sto), query was: INSERT INTO `mg_cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `min_qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`, `min_sale_qty`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `max_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `enable_qty_increments`, `is_decimal_divided`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2019-07-27 07:09:08', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /home/goodma20/project1.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`goodma20_test25072019`.`mg_cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `MG_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `mg_cataloginventory_stock` (`sto) at /home/goodma20/project1.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
[2019-07-27 07:22:56] main.CRITICAL: No such entity with id = 6300 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with id = 6300 at /home/goodma20/project1.com/vendor/magento/framewo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fixed issue by this
>
> query

```
insert into `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) values (1,0,'Default');
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it removing all Magento MSI modules through this package below since I was not using the MSI feature:

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory:2.3.*
```